# Добавление элемента в JsonArray

Tags: java, json

Нужно реализовать добавление элемента в существующий JsonArray. Изначально он выглядит примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новый элемент по какой-то причине добавляется вот в таком виде (см. task4):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу код добавления элемента:

```
public static void addTask(String filepath) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите название задачи:");
    String taskName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Введите описание задачи:");
    String taskDescription = sc.nextLine();
    String taskState = "No";

    Task task = new Task(taskName, taskDescription, taskState);

    JsonArray json = readJson(filepath);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    json.add(gson.toJson(task));
    try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(filepath)) {
        gson.toJson(json, writer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Также код класса Task:

```
public class Task {
    public String taskName;
    public String taskDescription;
    public String taskState;

    public Task(String taskName, String taskDescription, String taskState) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.taskDescription = taskDescription;
        this.taskState = taskState;
    }
}
```

В чем моя ошибка? Изначально Json создается из коллекции объектов класса Task, затем я хочу иметь возможность добавлять новый такой объект к уже существующему Json.

Comment: то есть у вас проблема при добавлении больше 3 элементов массива?

Comment: @Andrew в принципе при добавлении нового элемента с помощью addTask().

Comment: Есть две возможных проблемы - вы не так записываете в файл ваш json либо вы не так записываете json который потом пишете в файл) то есть вам нужно в консоль вывести то что получается после добавление в массив и потом то что вы записали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы добавляете `task` как строку JSON вида, а нужно добавлять как `JsonElement`

```
JsonElement taskElement = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(task), JsonElement.class);
json.add(taskElement);
```